# Trying to create well formed JSON data from MySQL database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json, database

I am making an application in which I pull data from an SQL database. My php code echos json data but its not well formed. My current output does not have a name of the array of results, and I would like it to - I have provided a link to a picture of how I would like the output to look. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php
// database settings 
$db_username = "****";
$db_password = "****";
$db_name = "****";
$db_host = "****";


   //open connection to mysql db
    $connection = mysqli_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_password","$db_name") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));

    //fetch table rows from mysql db
    $sql = "select * from markers";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($connection));

    //create an array
    $emparray = array();
    while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $emparray[] = $row;
    }


$data = array($emparray);

 echo json_encode($data);
    //close the db connection
    mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

[Final JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcKPx.png)
[Current Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojpui.png)

Comment: Do you mean something like: `$emparray[$specimenName] = $row`? That will allow you to make your array keys whatever you want instead of 0,1,2,3...

Comment: Well... add the name?! `$data = array('specimens' => $emparray);`

Comment: Perfect, that was it. Sorry new to PHP so didn't know how to name the array correctly. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you replace line

```
$data = array($emparray);
```

with

```
$data = array('markers' => $emparray);
```

?

It should output something like

```
JSON : {"markers":[{"id":1,"lorem":"ipsum"},{"id":2,"lorem":"dolor"}]}

php > var_dump($test);
array(1) {
  ["markers"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(1)
      ["lorem"]=>
      string(5) "ipsum"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(2)
      ["lorem"]=>
      string(5) "dolor"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This was it, Thank you!